# Simple connectedness of an ellipse

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $S = \{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z+i|+|z-i| = 4\}.$

I understand this is the set of points which trace an ellipse. I think this is  connected, as if I pick any two points, I can always form a path (along the ellipse), but this is not simply connected, as I can't shrink any two points to a closed loop "small enough".

Is there a way to show this more "formally"?

Comment: For connectedness, use path-connectedness. For simple connectedness, what tools in topology do you have?

Comment: The ellipse is clearly homeomorphic to a circle. What do you know about the circle ?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure, this is just introduced in complex analysis very briefly; we learnt open/closed sets, interior, boundary, exterior boundary points.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm not sure what that's alluding to

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours did you cover these properties for the circle?

Comment: Which properties?

Answer (score 0):

The ellipse in your question (which I'll call $E$, for brevity) is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$.

Recall that for a space $X$ to be simply connected, it must be path connected and it's fundamental group must be trivial, $\pi_1(X) = \{[c_p]\}$, where $c_p$ is the constant path.

Now the fundamental group $\pi_1$ of $S^1$ is the ring of integers, so $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and since homeomorphic topological spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups, we have $\pi_1(E) \cong \pi(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $\pi_1(E)$ has a nontrivial fundamental group we can conclude that it is not simply connected.

---

As an aside, one usually first encounters simple-connectedness in any introduction to Algebraic Topology.